Maximum number of elements on list whose value sum up to at most K in O(log n)
I have this exercise to do:
Let M be a positive integer, and V = ⟨v1, . . . , vn⟩ an ordered vector where the value of item vi is 5×i.
Present an O(log(n)) algorithm that returns the maximum number of items from V that can be selected given that the sum of the selected items is less than or equal to M (repeated selection of items is not allowed).
First I did a naive solution where:

I know the sum of elements on the array will be always less than the M/5 index on the array. So a did for i=0..i<=M/5 and found the sum. Moreover this is not O(log(n)) because given a big M, bigger than the sum of all elements on the array, it will be O(n).

Therefore I tried divide and conquer, I thought a binary search should be the way. But actually no because if I do that I will sum the minimum elements that can be chosen to arrive in M, not the maximum. My code is below
   def max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, left, right, max):

    if len(V[left:right]) == 1:
      return max
    

    mid =  math.floor((left+right)/2)
    if  V[mid] >= M:
        return max_items_selected_recursive2(M - V[mid], V, mid + 1, right, max+1)
    else:
        if  M - V[mid] >= 0:
          return max_items_selected_recursive2(M - V[mid], V, left, mid - 1, max+1)
        else: 
          return max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, left, mid - 1, max)
   

example of call
M = 20
  V = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
  max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, 0, len(V) - 1, 0) +1 # +1 since all have the O element

Any ideas on how to do this on O(log n)?

Given k, can you calculate v1+v2+...+vk quickly in your head?

Yes, but it's O(n) as I told before. I would do like 5+10+...until M, which is O(n) at worst case, when M more or equal to the sum of all array. And here the problem is to find in log(n), as explained in the question. Sorry if on the question is not clear, I will try to put in bold to leave it more evident

"Yes, but it's O(n) as I told before" That's not quickly in your head. You need to be able to do it quickly in your head before you can even attempt to write a line of code.

So no, I can't do quickly in my head

So you need to learn hopw to do that. It is not a programming problem, it is a math problem. Look up "sum of arithmetic series"

I mean, I know that I can do a sum of arithmetic series like n*(n+1)/2. But this is not (log n), it's like O(1). So since I'm studying coding problems I wonder I could solve this by programming, not by using a ready math formula which is known

"since I'm studying coding problems" In my opinion you are not really studying coding problems, you are studying math problems disguised as coding problems. "I wonder I could solve this by programming, not by using a ready math formula" What ready math formula exactly? If M=1553, what is the answer, according to that formula? Can you compute it in O(1)?

So here you are saying the only way possible to solve this problem is using the sum of arithmetic series and no binary search without using this formula can help? Because if there is a binary search solution, that is what I am searching for here with this question, this can also be a programming problem. ;)

Well yes in fact you can use the sum of arithmetic series formula and given the sum, solve for n. But you don't have to. You can also use a binary search and compute the sum given n at each step, if you want to.

Yes!! The "You can also use a binary search and compute the sum given n at each step, if you want to. " is the solution I tried to do and posted on the question the code I did and I cannot make it work. Do you have any suggestion on how can I do that?

The sum 1 + 2 + ... + n = n * (n+1) / 2.
The sum 5 + 10 + ... + 5n = 5 * (1 + 2 + ... + n) = 5 * n * (n+1) / 2.
So given an M, we want to solve for n so that 5 * n * (n+1) / 2 <= M. Then, add 1 to this to account for zero.
You can use the quadratic formula for an O(1) (which is also O(log n)) solution, or binary search on n for an O(log n) solution.

Hi, thanks for the answer! Can you develop further the binary search solution, please?

@CatarinaNogueira If M==0 then n is 0. Otherwise, set n=1 and keep doubling n until 5n(n+1)/2 > M. This takes log time. Now you have the two adjacent powers of 2 that surround the value you're looking for. normal binary search between those also in log time.

@CatarinaNogueira That said, all O(1) algorithms are also O(n) so it's cleaner / faster / fits the requirements to use the O(1) solution.

......too easy!

Your solution is almost there. It has two flaws.
def max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, left, right):
    if left == right:
      return left
    
    mid =  math.floor((left+right)/2) 

    arithmetic_med = 5* (mid*(mid+1)/2)

    arithmetic_med_plus_1 = 5* (mid+1*((mid+1)+1)/2)    # <--- one
    
    if arithmetic_med <= M and arithmetic_med_plus_1 >=M: # <--- two
      return mid
    elif arithmetic_med <= M:
        return max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, mid + 1, right)
    else:
        return max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, left, mid - 1)

First, mid+1*((mid+1)+1)/2 is not what you want. This expression takes ((mid+1)+1)/2, multiplies it by 1 (so a no-op), and then adds mid. It looks like you forgot some parentheses. What you want instead is (mid+1)*(mid+2)/2 (note adding 1 twice is the same thing as adding 2).
Second, the >= comparison is incorrect. When an exact equality is achieved, you return mid, but that's too small. The correct answer would be mid+1, because adding that many array members yields exactly M. You need to change that >= to >.

Thanks! For the #two I was calling with max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, 0, len(V) - 1)+1, so the issue was solved on the call =)

An implementation using Python's binary search:
from bisect import bisect

M = 1_000_000
n = 10_000

print(bisect(
    range(n+1),
    False,
    key=lambda i: 5*i*(i+1)//2 > M
) - 1)

Output (Attempt This Online!):
631

The range provides the possible numbers of items (0 to n, inclusive), the key function tells whether a given number i is too large. Then bisect finds the smallest number that's too large, and I subtract 1 to get the largest number that's not too large.

Hi! Thanks for sharing. Unfortunately this does not help me because I understand I should binary search but I could not create the algorithm without the arithmetic sum. So calling the python function with the arithmetic sum is the same as I did before, but here you are using the python functions. Thanks anyway :)

@CatarinaNogueira What would help you? It looks like you insist on something that's impossible, instead of doing what the exercise wants you to do, and it's still a mystery why you do that.

I would like to solve not using the arithmetic formula. If is impossible ok, thanks for the clarification.

@CatarinaNogueira Will you get an official solution for the exercise? I'm curious what that looks like.

Unfortunately I won't, the teacher do not give solutions :'(

With a suggestion of @dave and @n. m. could be an AI of using an arithmetic sum we have the code below that do work that use the arithmetic sum + binary search on O(log n):
def max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, left, right):
    if left == right:
      return left
    
    mid =  math.floor((left+right)/2) 

    arithmetic_med = 5* (mid*(mid+1)/2)

    arithmetic_med_plus_1 = 5* (mid+1*((mid+1)+1)/2)
    
    if arithmetic_med <= M and arithmetic_med_plus_1 >=M:
      return mid
    elif arithmetic_med <= M:
        return max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, mid + 1, right)
    else:
        return max_items_selected_recursive2(M, V, left, mid - 1)

Moreover I didn't wanted to use an arithmetic sum, I wanted to use only pure binary search. This I still don't know how to do.

"I didn't wanted to use an arithmetic sum" - Why? Something like this is likely the intended solution.

Because I don't realise this at the beginning I could use the formula and I tried to do without and I couldn't. So I would really like to know how to do it so I can understand why I could not before

(1) (mid+1*((mid+1)+1)/2) I don't think you mean that. Perhaps there are some parentheses missing? (2) I don't think this is totally correct, test for M=5,15,30,50,75,105. You need to get consecutive numbers but this program outputs 1,3,3,4,6,6. Perhaps you want to revise this condition if arithmetic_med <= M and arithmetic_med_plus_1 >=M:. What happens if you get arithmetic_med_plus_1 ==M?

@n.m.couldbeanAI for which M are you saying that the array 5,15,30,50,75,105 do not work? The algorithm returns the maximum number of items from V that can be selected given that the sum of the selected items is less than or equal to M .

Also, from the specification "where the value of item vi is 5×i.", so your array is actually invalid, it should have a 0, 10 etc

@CatarinaNogueira V should not have a 0, it starts with 5 since i starts with 1.

This version doesn't use an array at all, it just passes it around without ever looking at it. So it doesn't matter what's in it. I show values of M that I tested. Whether you start from 0 or from 1, these values should produce consecutive results. They do not.

@n.m.couldbeanAI What values did you use for left and right? (Really shouldn't be necessary to provide them, btw, argh...)

@nocomment 0 and 100

@n.m.couldbeanAI Hmm, with that I get 0, 2, 4, 4 and then a recursion limit error.

@nocomment don't know about recursion linit error, I don't get that, but now I get 0,2,2,3,5,5 (still wrong).

@nocomment ah that's because of that mid+1*. I fixed that in my copy.

I don't understand the solution you proposed. Fell free to leave an answer on SO so it's easier than on comments :)
